# How to instruct MatrixLog to work with singular matrices?

Tags: functions, matrix, linear-algebra

How to instruct `MatrixLog` to work with singular matrices by ignoring the zero eigenvalues (thus only acting on a subspace orthogonal to the matrix kernel)?

I'm trying to avoid the arduous journey of getting the eigenvectors (takes a long time) to be able to diagonalize, 'manually' apply the `Log` function and then go back to the original basis where the matrix is not diagonal.

Comment: Could you post some sample data for us to try out? It would make experimenting with alternatives easier.

Comment: @Pillsy `n = 5;
m = Partition[Range[n^2], n];
NullSpace[m]`

Comment: @Pillsy Yes, essentially any square matrix of dimension $d$ whose rank is less than $d$, like in belisarius' example.

Comment: `MatrixLog[]` was never really intended to deal with matrices with eigenvalues lying in the branch cut of the scalar logarithm function. (Conversely, one can never expect `MatrixExp[]` to return a singular matrix.) I have to wonder exactly what application is having you consider matrix gymnastics of this sort...

Comment: In any case, if you do proceed with diagonalization, are you proposing to just take the logarithm of the nonzero eigenvalues, and leave the zero eigenvalues as they are?

Comment: @J.M.In quantum mechanics it is quite common to evaluate the entropy of a quantum state: $-Tr(\rho\log\rho)$. There, you have an $n$-level quantum state $\rho$ but its rank can be less than $n$. In this case $\log(\rho)$ gives nonsense results and to get it right, it is natural to ignore the null space.

Answer (score 1):

I use two different definitions in this case. Numerically it seems to suffice to add a fraction of identity. Just make sure the accuracy/stability is good enough for you.

```
MatrixLogSafe[x_?(MatrixQ[#1, NumericQ] &)] := MatrixLog[x + 1.`*^-9 IdentityMatrix[Length[x]]]/Log[2];
```

For symbolic expressions I find MatrixFunction convenient:

```
MatrixLogSafe[x_] := MatrixFunction[Piecewise[{{Log2[#1], #1 > 0}}] &, x];
```

Note that the definitions are for base 2, but you can easily adjust them if that's the convention in your context.

**Edit:** By the way, in the application you mention in the comment it seems you don't need the matrix log at all, because you could directly calculate the entropy via

```
H[x_]:=-Total[Piecewise[{{# Log2[#], # > 0}}] & /@ Eigenvalues[x]]
```